# self-signed certificate for server on local network?

Tags: ios, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a system for transferring data between an iOS device and a Windows machine which are on a Wifi network, but not connected to the internet.

I am running a simple HTTP server (using [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib)) on the Windows machine.  The iOS app uses the usual URLRequest and URLSession classes to connect to the server via IP address.

This all works, using plain HTTP, but I would like to use a HTTPS connection.
I created a certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 36500
```

and gave the cert and key files to the server.  However, iOS refuses to connect to the server, with the error "The certificate for this server is invalid".

As far as I can understand, this is called a "self-signed certificate" and is not normally trusted by iOS.  I don't think I can get a certificate from a CA, because I don't have a domain name associated with this server.

I *think* the right way to do this is to generate my own "root" certificate, and install it on the iOS device, and sign the server certificates with this root certificate.  Is that actually the right way?  And how do I generate these certificates?